# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

**Это было прекрасно(-) путешествовать по миру.**

Answer (score 2):

ernest00 всегда задаёт очень интересные вопросы. На них хочется ответить сразу, они кажутся лёгкими, но... Только в первую секунду. Я тоже сразу удалила свой ответ, цитату из ПАС Лопатина, потому что тут всё не так просто.
  Дело в том, что в качестве сказуемого здесь выступает выражение "было прекрасно" - слово категории состояния + БЫЛО. (Я сторонница спорного утверждения, что КС может быть сказуемым в двусоставном предложении). А тире между инфинитивом и словом категории состояния(или краткого прилагательного, наречия?) - это особая тема. Рассматриваются ПОСТпозиция и ПРЕпозиция инфинитива по отношению к слову КС, в зависимости от этого ставится или не ставится знак. 
У нас при сказуемом употреблена указательная частица ЭТО. И у нас есть связка БЫЛО. 
***Если бы не слово ЭТО***, предложение выглядело бы так:
***Было прекрасно путешествовать по миру.*** И: ***Путешествовать по миру было прекрасно***. Тире **не** ставится в обоих случаях, потому что между инфинитивом-подлежащим и словом "прекрасно"есть связка ***было***. 
Сравним: ***Путешествовать по миру - это было прекрасно.*** Тире несомненно. Указательная частица ЭТО потребовала знак. И в предложении **"Это было прекрасно - путешествовать по миру"** тире тоже необходимо. Подлежащее "путешествовать", сказуемое "было прекрасно".

```
    Ребята, ура! Нашла подтверждение своей версии (http://www.classes.ru/grammar/127.Rosental-pravopisanie/42.htm)
```

1. Тире ставится между ***подлежащим, выраженным неопределенной формой глагола***, и ***сказуемым, выраженным предикативным наречием на -о***, если между главными членами предложения делается пауза, например: Готовиться к экзаменам – не так просто (Федин); Уступить – позорно (В. Тендряков); ***Это очень несносно – переезжать*** (Гончаров).
   Но (при отсутствии паузы): Судить человека в немилости очень легко (Л. Толстой).

Так что подлежащее в нашем примере всё-таки "путешествовать".

Comment: Собственно говоря, Лопатину это не противоречит. Просто у него правило сформулировано попроще. Всё определяется тем, можно ли вставить вместо тире слова "а именно". Удаление частицы "это" автоматически проблематизирует такую вставку, поскольку эти слова могут быть связаны только с частицей "это". Только что заметил ещё более простой рецепт. Нужно просто мысленно поменять местами части предложения. Если после этого всё ещё хочется поставить тире, то значит и в оригинале надо. Без "это" получится "путешествовать по миру было прекрасно". Лично у меня начисто пропадает желание поставить тире.

Comment: Вы не поняли Лопатина. возможность вставки "а именно" - признак, а не тпричина. При этом и признак-то не абсолютный.

Comment: @EkaterinaKas..., а разве "это" здесь частица? Что-то я сомневаюсь... Или у нас уже разрешили частицам выступать в роли подлежащего? *Я правда не знаю, ибо не слежу - и никогда не следил - за колебаниями академических подходов.*

Comment: @EkaterinaKas... Кстати, он прав. В данном случае слово "это" является местоимением.

Comment: @Shamov, я всегда прав. Для этого ваше участие не требуется.

Comment: ЭТО часто бывает частицей (http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&stype=0). Я тоже долго сомневалась, чем ЗДЕСЬ является ЭТО. Очень похоже на подлежащее в части "это было прекрасно", и тогда это местоимение, конечно. Только вот слово "путешествовать" тоже претендует на эту роль. Как-то не очень на определение оно похоже. Впрочем, готова согласиться на этот вариант, ибо до сих пор не совсем уверена в правильности своего ответа. Уроки проведу - додумаю.

Comment: Короче, получается одна из двух равноправных трактовок. "Путешествовать" является либо подлежащим, либо инфинитивным разъясняющим определением. В первом случае мой трюк с переворотом вокруг тире как бы восстанавливает естественный порядок слов. "Это" оказывается частицей, отрицать это невозможно, и поэтому нужно тире. Во втором случае тире нужно по причине Лопатина.

Answer (score 1):

Пользователь [@olsa](/users/246/olsa) почему-то удалил свой ответ. Хотя именно он помог мне понять, что мой ответ был неправильным. Поэтому возьму на себя смелость восстановить этот ответ, снабдив его соответствующей цитатой из правил.

> Инфинитив в качестве определения
> отделяется от определяемого слова
> знаком тире, если определяемое имя уже
> имеет при себе определение.
> Инфинитивное определение в таком
> случае приобретает смысл
> дополнительного разъяснения (возможна
> вставка слов а именно): Сбывалась
> старая вихровская мечта — еще раз
> прикоснуться щекой к суховатой,
> вскормившей его груди (Леон.).
> Обособленные инфинитивные определения,
> распространенные и нераспространенные,
> располагаются в конце предложения: — Я
> наложу на всех одну обязанность —
> творить (М. Г.); А почему бы вам,
> скажем, не задаться простой и очень
> важной целью — сэкономить средства,
> выделенные государством вашей школе
> (газ.).

Так что да... тире нужно.

Comment: Вряд ли пользователь (тем более - столь здесь уважаемый) без причины удалил свой комментарий.
Возможно, это сделал модератор.
В любом случае не стоит на него ссылаться, говорите от своего имени, если уверены. Возражать-то будут все равно вам.

По сути, я крепко сомневаюсь, что здесь случай, подпадающий под вами цитируемый. Какое слово по-Вашему здесь является определяемым? Неужели "прекрасно"? Определяемое слово лмбо "это", но оно стоит далеко от тире, либо в роли такого слова выступает вся конструкция "это было прекрасно". Но по этому поводу ничего не сказано даже у Лопатина.

Comment: А вот ссылку давать на цитату вас так и не приучили.
Это не "правила", это *Лопатин, "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации"*. 

http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/

Comment: Вы правы. Ваши комментарии бесконечно обогатили мой ответ.

Comment: Его уже ничто не обогатит. Вы же не в состоянии ответиь на вопросы.

Comment: Не скромничайте. Вам, безусловно, удалось обогатить мой ответ столь ценным содержанием, что у меня даже нет слов.

Comment: Отнюдь. Жемчуга - мои, но навоз-то - ваш.

Answer (score 0):

Тире нужно. Без него смысл теряется. Или запятая - тут я без автора не могу сказать наверняка, боюсь, тут возможно двоякое понимание синтаксиса.

В обосновние тире:

§ 18. Обособленные определения

Несогласованные определения
3. Несогласованные определения, выраженные неопределенной формой глагола, перед которой можно без ущерба для смысла поставить слова а именно, отделяются посредством тире: …Я шёл к вам с чистыми побуждениями, с единственным желанием — сделать добро! (Ч.); Но прекрасен данный жребий — просиять и умереть (Бр.); …Мы все одержимы одной страстью — сопротивляться (Кетл.); С батареи получен приказ — не отнимать трубку от уха и каждые пять минут проверять линию (Кат.); Своей беззащитностью она вызывала в нём рыцарские чувства — заслонить, оградить, защитить; Откуда вы право взяли себе такое — судить? Подобные определения носят пояснительный характер (см. § 23, п. 1).
(Розенталь ["Справочник по русскому языку"](http://www.modernlib.ru/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read))
...

Comment: Тогда что будет являться грамматической основой предложения?

Comment: Обычное, двусоставное.
"Это" - подлежащее, "было прекрасно" - сказуемое, "путешествовать по миру" - как и следует из цитаты - обособленное определение. 

Другое дело, что сама трактовка неоднозначная. Можно, как и говорил через зщапятую написать. Тогда, возможно, будет другой синтаксис. Двуосновное сложносочиненное. 
Но вообще-то я в эти академические споры не хотел бы влезать, это в общем-то спор о вкусах, как что назвать.

Comment: Все верно. Подлежащее, сказуемое, определение.

Comment: Ларf, определение тогда  относится к ЭТО? Получается: ЭТО (какое?)ПУТЕШЕСТВОВАТЬ. Не звучит! Что-то тут не так.

Comment: Что вопрос не звучит - так бывает. Вспомните местоименно-определительные придаточные. Там тоже вопрос от местоимения, и тоже "не звучит". Как и в вопросе со сказуемым, хотелось бы почитать еще кого-нибудь, помимо Розенталя.